# What is the meaning of these special characters in Linux command?

Tags: linux, shell

According to https://www.cs.washington.edu/lab/faq/home-directory-size:

> To display the aggregate size of each file or subdirectory (including hidden files and subdirectories) contained within the current directory, sorted by size (largest first), run the following command:
>
> ```
> du -sk * .??* | sort -nr
> ```

What is the meaning of symbols after `-sk` and before pipe, `* .??*`?

As a bonus question, where/how can I find this kind of thing (a combination of special characters in a command line in Linux) using Google? I tried searching, but I couldn't find much since they are just punctuation.

Comment: Check the bash manpage: `After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching below).`

Comment: Or look at section 2.13 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13

Comment: It's supposed to run `du` on all files and hidden files while avoiding the current directory itself (`.`) and its parent (`..`) by requiring a leading `.` to be followed by at least two characters; this is buggy, though, as a hidden file named like `.a` would be ignored.

Comment: The secret is to know that it is not a Linux command (Linux is just the kernel), this is a bash (shell) command. It is called globing. You can read about it in the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 3):

They're the usual filename [wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/wildcards/info) or [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) or [pattern match](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) characters. `?` matches any single character, `*` any number of any characters.

The exception is filenames starting with a dot `.`, which a leading `*` will *not* match (so they're "hidden" files). Hence, `*` will match any file with a name not starting with a dot, and `.??*` will match any files with names starting with a dot, and with at least three characters. The latter is what it is because it tries to avoid `.` and `..`, but it would also  miss e.g. `.a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 du -sk * .??* | sort -nr
```

this is a du on exactly :

1. *(all) subdirectories   or files
2. .??* (all) hiden directories or files with at least 2 characters on their names

then results are sorted

@ilkkachu mentionned .??*/ whould be used to show directories only

Comment: Appending a `/` with `.??*/` would change the behaviour for symlinks. If you wanted files of type directory only including hidden ones with the exception of `.` and `..`, you'd use zsh and its `du -sk -- *(D/)`.